# How to Multiple node weight with its value then compute sum of all child nodes in parent child hierarchy using sql server 2008

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a scenario, where i have to find percentage of each child node by multiplying node value with node weight, (e.g NodeVal * (NodeWeight/100)), then sum these computed values of all child nodes and add it to its parent, now at one level up this newly computed parent also has its weight, which will be multiplied with its value and then we will compute sum of all child nodes at this level and add it to its parent one level above, and so on.

Queries found on internet work fine if we simply compute sum of all child nodes, but not helpful in my case.

I am using following query, but it does not return accurate result.

```
    CREATE TABLE TEMP(
      Id INT
      ,ParentNodeId INT
      ,Weight FLOAT
      ,Score FLOAT    
      );

      INSERT INTO TEMP
            VALUES (2, 1, 0, 0),
            (3, 2, 100, 0),
            (4, 2, 100, 0),
            (5, 2, 100, 0),
            (6, 3, 40, 100),
            (7, 3, 30, 0),
            (8, 3, 30, 100),
            (9, 7, 10, 100),
            (10, 7, 40, 100),
            (11, 7, 50, 0),
            (12, 11, 30, 100),
            (13, 11, 70, 0),
            (14, 13, 50, 100),
            (15, 13, 50, 100);


WITH cte(Id, ParentNodeId, LEVEL, Struc, Weight, Score)
            AS
            (
            SELECT t.Id, t.ParentNodeId, 0 AS LEVEL, CAST(':' + CAST(t.Id AS VARCHAR) + ':' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Struc, t.Weight, t.Score 
            FROM TEMP t
            WHERE t.ParentNodeId = 2 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT t.Id, t.ParentNodeId, LEVEL + 1 AS LEVEL, CAST(e.Struc + CAST(t.Id AS VARCHAR) + ':' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Struc, t.Weight, t.Score 
            FROM TEMP t
            INNER JOIN cte e ON e.Id = t.ParentNodeId           
            )

select c1.Id, c1.ParentnodeId, c1.weight, c1.score,c1.struc,
SUM(c2.score  * (c2.weight/100 )) ProductCountIncludingChildren
from cte c1
left outer join cte c2 on c1.struc <> c2.struc and left(c2.struc, LEN(c1.struc)) = c1.struc
group by c1.Id, c1.ParentnodeId, c1.weight, c1.score, c1.struc
order by c1.Id
```

This query works only at leave nodes, but not at above levels. [SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/958e3/15/0).

Please let me know, how this can be solved. Thanks for help in advance -:)

Comment: Thanks for the sample data. Can you also include the desired results?

Comment: desired output added as answer as i am unable to edit my question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to edit my question, so i am adding desired output as answer:

```
Id  P_Id    weight  score   ChildSum
3   2        100    0   100
4   2        100    0   (null)
5   2        100    0   (null)
6   3        40     100 (null)
7   3        30     0   100
8   3        30     100 (null)
9   7        10     100 (null)
10  7        40     100 (null)
11  7        50     0   100
12  11       30     100 (null)
13  11       70     0   100
14  13       50     100 (null)
15  13       50     100 (null)
```

Compute sum like this: childSum for Id 13 will be ([score of id 14] * ([weight of id 14 ]/100)) plus ([score of id 15] * ([ weight of id 15 ]/100) ) 
=>>> (100 * (50/100)) + (100 * (50/100)) => 100

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CTE but I opted to use a left join.

```
            Select  ID as ID,
                    ParentNodeId as P_ID,
                    Weight as Weight,
                    Score as Score,
                    isnull(Sums,0) as ChildSum
            From #TEMP
            Left Join ( Select  ParentNodeId as P_ID, 
                                isnull(Sum(Score*(Weight/100.0)),0) as Sums 
                        from #TEMP 
                        group by ParentNodeId
                        ) as ParSum on P_ID=ID
```

Hopefully what you are looking for

Comment: This does not compute sum of all child of parent correctly  when child may exist as parent too.

Comment: I have double checked and it seems to work great. Maybe just check your output? For ID=3 your formula states the result should be 100*(40/100)+0*(30/100)+100*(30/100)= 70 <> 100 as stated in your output. Apologies if I am misunderstanding the question. Also note in my output, ChildSum indicates the the sum for ID not P_ID

Comment: Please review my desired output again. Now we see Node id 13 is parent of both nodes 14 and 15. So, we will compute score of node 13 using formula ([score of id 14] * ([weight of id 14 ]/100)) plus ([score of id 15] * ([ weight of id 15 ]/100) ) , so at this point we have computed score of 13. No we see Node 11 is parent of both nodes 12 and 13, we will compute score of node 11 using formula ([score of id 12] * ([weight of id 12 ]/100)) plus ([score of id 13 recently computed in previous step] * ([ weight of id 13 ]/100) ). Please let me know if you got my point,else i 'll try to explain again